# Scroll firebase Recyclerview inside a scrollview to the last item inserted

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, scrollview

I've been through several solutions over the stack overflow but could not achieve the desired result. I have a firebase recyclerview for a comment section. The firebase recyclerview exist with in the scroll view as am scroll some other part of the layout as well with the normal firebase recyclerview. I've set `RecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)`, so the scrollview can scroll smoothly. right now I'm able to successfully scroll through out the layout but my problem only arises when I enter the activity the layout is shown from the top which is something, I don't want. I want the firebase recyclerview or the scroll view to be shown from the last item which is in the bottom. Also I want to the `RecyclerView` to automatically scroll to the last item position whenever the user enters a new comment

Any Help would be appreciated thank you

Below is my code

**the code inside the oncreate for initialization**

```
        replyInDetailCommentsRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.replyInDetailCommentsRecyclerView);
    linearLayoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    replyInDetailCommentsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager1);
    replyInDetailCommentsRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

**The code inside the firebase recyclerview, I've only added the relevant part to the problem. hope it helps**

```
     adapter1.startListening();
    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
    adapter1.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
            int friendlyMessageCount = adapter1.getItemCount();
            int lastVisiblePosition =
                    linearLayoutManager1.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

            if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
                    (positionStart >= (friendlyMessageCount - 1) &&
                            lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
                linearLayoutManager1.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
            } else {
                replyInDetailCommentsRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(adapter1.getItemCount() - 1);
            }
        }
    });


    replyInDetailCommentsRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter1);
    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**My XML Code**

```
   <ScrollView
    android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">






<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">



<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/RelativeLayout4">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/replyInDetailCommentsRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">




    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>










</RelativeLayout>




<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageInDetailComments"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

        android:layout_height="30dp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/nameInDetailComments"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageInDetailComments"
        tools:text="Saqib"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageInDetailComments"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

        android:textColor="#096697"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageInDetailComments"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingInDetailComments"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:max="5"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"

        android:progressTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:rating="0.0"
        android:secondaryProgressTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:stepSize="0.0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageInDetailComments"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameInDetailComments"

        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageInDetailComments" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/userCommentInDetailComments"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ratingInDetailComments"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageInDetailComments"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="#efeeee"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="i can do it mate, my bidding price includes gotaskie fee"
        />



    <View
            android:layout_below="@+id/userCommentInDetailComments"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/lineAboveCommentsRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#dad8d8"

        />

</RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Some suggestions for you. First use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`. You question is unclear provide snapshots also you are asking for features which you didn't coded. SO is only for bug fixes you can't ask like i want this i want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **NestedScrollView** instead of **ScrollView**